# The general structure of an $x-iy$ substitution in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, complex-numbers

In both the algebraic (a la Dirac) solution to the quantum SHO and in the algebraic approach to determining the spectra of the angular momentum operators (generators of rotations), substitutions of the form
$$x_+ = x+iy$$
$$x_- = x-iy$$
are employed. I remember reading an answer -- I think here on Phys SE -- which seemed to go deeper into why we think to use these substitutions in the first place, making a connection with basic manipulations of complex numbers. I can't seem to find it now, but if anyone can or if they are willing to write up another answer as to what is the motivation for making these substitutions in the first place I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Well, note that $x_+ x_- = (x+iy)(x-iy) = x^2+y^2$. This, for example. motivates the use of ladder operators in the case of the QHO.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I think this is exactly what I was looking for -- and then with operators we get another term all the way on the LHS due to the nonvanishing commutator. I will now have to think about how this maps to the angular momentum case. Feel free to put this as an answer and I'd be glad to accept.

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator#Angular_momentum) already for the angular momentum case? IIRC, there are many questions/answers here on SE regarding the motivation etc. for ladder operators.

Answer (score 0):

> In both the algebraic (a la Dirac) solution to the quantum SHO and in the algebraic approach to determining the spectra of the angular momentum operators (generators of rotations), substitutions of the form
> $$x_+ = x+iy$$
> $$x_- = x-iy$$
> are employed.

One reason the above substitutions are convenient when dealing with angular momenta is that the set of three functions $z$, $x_+$, and $x_-$ are all eigenfunctions of the z-axis angular momentum operator $L_z=-i\hbar\partial/\partial \phi$, with eigenvalues $0$, $+1$, and $-1$, respectively.

This is easier to see if we re-write $x_{\pm}$ as
$$
x_{\pm} = r\sin(\theta)e^{\pm i\phi}
$$
and
$$
z = r\cos(\theta)\;.
$$

---

Using these variables often simplifies problems when dealing with spherically symmetric potentials in the Schrodinger equation.

For example, you can create trial solutions in the form of products like
$$
\psi \sim z^{\nu_0} x_+^{\nu_+} x_-^{\nu}\;,
$$
subject to
$$
\ell = \nu_0 + \nu_+ + \nu_-
$$
and
$$
m = \nu_+ - \nu_-
$$
and thereby derive solutions of the form:
$$
\psi_{n\ell m}(\vec r) = R_{n\ell}(r)Y_{\ell m}(\theta, \phi)\;,
$$
where the $Y_{\ell m}$ are Spherical Harmonics.

---

> I remember reading an answer -- I think here on Phys SE -- which seemed to go deeper...

What you mean when you write "go deeper" is unclear. If you can, please provide some more objective description of what kind of explanation you are looking for. One can seemingly always argue, "no that wasn't deep enough of an explanation."